# "Теплые родственные отношения" - однородные или неоднородные?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика

*Поддерживает теплые родственные отношения.*

Считаю, что определения однородные, нужна запятая. У автора нет. Как правильно? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, это неоднородные определения. Предмет характеризуется с разных сторон. Здесь качественное прилагательное и относительное. Нельзя сказать: поддерживать и теплые отношения и родственные отношения.

Comment: Серж, а разве можно сказать: поддерживать плохие родственные отношения? Здесь само сочетание "ПОДДЕРЖИВАТЬ родственные отношение" означает "поддерживать теплые отношения".

Comment: Вера, видимо ***теплый***  указывает на разный признак, а ''дружеский" непосредственно на отличительный признак.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, это однородные определения. Поддерживать родственные отношения - это всегда поддерживать хорошие отношения.

**А вообще говоря, с этими родственными отношениями всё сложнее.** Наверное, существуют просто родственные отношения (их тоже надо поддерживать), нормальные родственные отношения, теплые родственные отношения.

**В то же время однородные определения также возможны:**

Он упорно и сурово говорил себе, что у них **дружеские, родственные** отношения, а больше ничего нет и не может быть.

Такого рода **добрые, чисто родственные отношения** соединяли дворню княгини Полторацкой с барыней и барышней.

Бобочка старался восстановить с Пинегиным **добрые, родственные отношения**, и как-то за ужином в ресторане предлагал выпить на брудершафт.

Comment: Они могут быть однородными только если "родственные" употреблены не в прямом смысле.

Comment: Вы считаете, что в приведенных примерах говорится о ненастоящих родственных отношениях ?

Comment: Во втором уж точно. К тому же там еще и "чисто", что как раз и говорит о том, что на самом деле не "чисто". В первом... Зачем себя убеждать "упорно и сурово", если они и так родственные?

Comment: В первом и третьем случае речь идет о настоящих родственных отношениях, и они приравнены к дружеским и добрым, только с разной целью: в первом - чтобы противопоставить их любовным отношениям, а в третьем - чтобы вернуть родственным отношениям их  определяющее качество как добрых отношений, то есть ВОССТАНОВИТЬ отношения.

Answer (score 0):

При желании можно, конечно, считать однородными (теплые И родственные). Но только при очень большом желании.